# Using 'like', '<=' and '=' operators when building an SQLAlchemy query filter from dict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I currently have a python dictionary that is created from the data that a user submits through a form. The form fields are optional, but if they are all filled out, then the dictionary (`dict_filter`) might look like this:

> {"item_type": "keyboard", "location": "storage1"}

I can then query the database as shown:

```
items = Item.query.filter_by(**dict_filter).all()
```

This works fine and returns all the `keyboard` items that are currently in `storage1` as desired.

However, I want to add two new date fields to the form such that a completely filled out form would result in a dictionary similar to the following:

> {"item_type": "keyboard", "location": "storage1", "purchase_date": 2017-02-18, "next_maintenance": 2018-02-18}

Based on this new dict, I would like to do the following:

First, use `like()` when filtering the `item_type`. I want this so that if a user searches for `keyboard` then the results will also include items like `mechanical keyboard` for example. I know I can do this individually as shown:

```
val = form.item_type.data
items = Item.query.filter(getattr(Item, 'item_type').like("%%%s%%" % val)).all()
```

Second, use the '<=' (less than or equal to) operator when dealing with dates such that if, for example, a user enters a `purchase_date` in the form, then all the items returned will have a `purchase_date` before or on the same date as entered by the user. I know I can do this individually as shown:

```
items = Item.query.filter(Item.purchase_date <= form.purchase_date.data)
```

Note that if both dates are filled out in the form, then the filter should check both dates as shown:

```
items = Item.query.filter(and_(Item.purchase_date <= form.purchase_date.data, Item.next_maintenance <= form.next_maintenance.data))
```

Third, if the `location` field is filled out in the form, then the query should check for items with matching locations (as it currently does with the dict). I know I can do this using a dict as I am currently doing:

```
dict = {"location": "storage1"}
items = Item.query.filter_by(**dict_filter).all()
```

or

```
items = Item.query.filter_by(location=form.location.data).all()
```

The greatest challenge that I have is that since the form fields are optional I have no way of knowing beforehand what combination of filter conditions I'll have to apply. Therefore, it may be possible that for one user's input, I'll have to search the db for all `screen` items in `office1` with `next_maintenance` date before `yyyy-mm-dd` while for another user's input I'll have to search the db for all items in all location regardless of `next_maintenance` date with a `purchase_date` before `yyyy-mm-dd`, and so on. This is precisely why I'm currently using a dict as a filter; it allows me to check if a form field was completed and if it was, then I add it to the dict and filter only based on form fields with input.

**With all that being said, how can I combine all three filters discussed above (like, <=, =) into one while also accounting for the fact that not all three filters may always be necessary?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not intended to be an answer but a comment. But apparently I can't use code block in a comment.

In case you don't know, you can use multiple `filter` or `filter_by` by chaining them together like this:

```
Item.query.filter(Item.a < 5).filter(Item.b > 6).all()
```

Therefore you can store the returning value as a variable (it is actually an object of `Query`) temporarily and use it later.

```
q = Item.query.filter(Item.a < 5)

if some_condition_value:
    q = q.filter(Item.b > 6)

items = q.all()
```

You can apply your conditions to the `Query` object and then you can have optional filters.

Comment: This worked wonderfully. I did not know that you could chain filters together. This allowed me to still use a dict as a base filter and then add additional filters when necessary. Thank you very much!